# How to convert meters to miles

Tags: javascript, distance, formula

I want to convert meters to miles in JavaScript.

For example 12700 meters is 7.8867 miles.

What formula can I use to do the conversion?

Comment: `var distanceInMiles = distanceInMetres / 1609;`

Comment: Where `metres` is a number, you can do this to convert that to miles: `eval('metres/'+(1/2*Math.PI*-1e6*~Math.E-!0-273326.98038468976+'').split('').reverse().join('')+'e'+~2)`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
function getMiles(meters) {
     return meters*0.000621371192;
}
function getMeters(miles) {
     return miles*1609.344;
}
```